# What solution is not in equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, solutions

> An example of a solution not in equilibrium
>   (A) Chemical ph
>   indicator
>   (B) Acid/base buffer
>   (C) Anhydrous solution
>   (D)
>   hypotonic solution
>   (E) Supersaturated solution

I  eliminated A and B. Then, I chose E, which is a right answer. Nonetheless, I read then that theoretically any solution or system can be in equilibrium. So, why is the answer E but not C or D?

Comment: Supersaturated solution just can't be in equilibrium, otherwise it would not be supersaturated.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Isn't there an equilibrium established between the solid crystals and the solution? This is a dynamic process, is it not? I am unsure myself. Please clarify.

Comment: The situation when there is an equilibrium between the solid crystals and the solution is called **saturated** solution. The "**super**" part tells us quite explicitly that we are in a different situation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sorry got confused